# Getting entry from many to many mapping table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that are mapped together with a mapping table; the tables are as follows:

- data
- metadata
- matadata_map

`metadata_map` is mapping `data` together with `metadata`.
In the `metadata_map` table, I need to map some IDs together. I need to find out which `data` ids have X, Y .. N `metadata` ids.
The `metadata_map` table could look like the following:

```
--------------------
| data_id| meta_id |
--------------------
| 1      | 2       |
| 1      | 3       |
| 2      | 1       |
| 2      | 2       |
| 3      | 1       |
| 3      | 2       |
| 3      | 3       |
| 3      | 4       |
--------------------
```

In this example, I will try to find out which `data_id`s has both `meta_id`s 2 and 3.
When looking up in the `metadata_map` table, I should get the result: (1, and 3)

```
----------
| data   |
----------
| 1      |
| 3      |
----------
```

since both `data_id` 1 and 3 has `meta_id` 2 and 3.

My question is, how can I best match them together in PostgreSQL to get the result?
This also requires that it's highly performant because the table has, at the moment of typing, about ~700mil entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping

```
 select data_id
 from metadata_map 
 where meta_id in (2,3)
 group by data_id
 having count(*) = 2
```

The query assumes `metadata_map` contains no dups. Alternatively use `count(distinct meta_id)`.

Comment: Well, there is a problem. Records (2, 2) and (2, 2) will falsely qualify 2. `count(distinct meta_id)` instead of `count(*)` will yield correct results.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm,  that's correct. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative - using an array:

```
 select data_id
 from metadata_map 
 group by data_id
 having array_agg(meta_id) @> array[2,3];
```

This query retrieves `data_id`s that have both meta_id 2 and meta_id 3 but may have others too.

```sql
having array_agg(meta_id order by meta_id) = array[2,3];
```

would retrieve `data_id`s that have exactly meta_id 2 and meta_id 3 and no others.
The pattern can be reused with other [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) too.