# query exact match in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

items :

```
id | name  | ref
---|-------|----
1  |item 1 | x2
2  |item 2 | x3
```

options:

```
id | option_id | item_id 
---|-----------|--------
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 2         | 1
2  | 3         | 1
2  | 1         | 2
2  | 3         | 2
```

given item ref = 'x2' and array of options [1,2,3] I should get 1 row of item 1 with exact options. given item 1 with options [1,2] should return null.

I tried this but could not get the result:

```
  SELECT items.*,(
    SELECT  options.id
    FROM    options, items
    WHERE   options.option_id IN (1,2,3) AND options.item_id = items.id 
   GROUP BY options.id, items.id
   HAVING COUNT(options.*) = 2)
   FROM items WHERE items.ref = 'x2';
```

what will be the best options?

Comment: Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493079/getting-entry-from-many-to-many-mapping-table) SO question may give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way by making an array of options and compare them :

```
select * from items i 
join ( select item_id , ARRAY_AGG(option_id order by option_id) optionids
       from options 
       group by item_id
) o  on i.id = o.item_id
where ref = 'x2'
and optionids <@ array[1,3,2]
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=185fb70a6bf5f65b4d0ccaf9e8fdddb5)*

Comment: is there any way that i can explicitly select the item with the same reference lets say there is item3 with ref 'x2' but different options [2,3]. the code above shows me 2 rows. i need only 'x2' and options [1,2,3] "exactly"?

Comment: i got it , i just changed the "<@" to "=" and added another criteria orders.name  = 'item 1', as i needed it. thanks @eshirvana